# jQuery animate: How do I prevent value from changing?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, dimensions

I am animating a div called $('.plan'). I want to grab its originalWidth in a variable and NOT have this value change after hover animation *so I can return to it after the animation has completed.*

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var $plan = $('.plan'),
    origWidth = $plan.width();

    $plan.hover(function() {
        $this = $(this);
        $this.stop().animate({width: 200, backgroundColor:'#a4a4a4'}, 500)      
    }, function() {
        $this.stop().animate({width: origWidth, backgroundColor:'#e2e2e2'}, 200)
    });

});
```

How do I do this?

Hey it seems like its working now. How come?

Comment: What is wrong?  What error/issue are you experiencing with this code?

Comment: Try slapping a 'var' in front of that origWidth variable. Based on your code, I don't see why it should ever change (even with or without my latter suggestion).

Comment: @Romanulus There is a comma between the two variable declarations so `origWidth` technically does have a `var`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function() {

    var $plan     = $('.plan'),
        origWidth = $plan.width();

    $plan.hover(function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({width: 200, backgroundColor:'#a4a4a4'}, 500)      
    }, function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({width: origWidth, backgroundColor:'#e2e2e2'}, 200)
    });

});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Dc367/

All that I really changed are the `$this` references, you don't really need to cache a selection if you aren't going to use it more than once. And you didn't declare a `$this` variable in the second `.hover()` function so I'll assume that's where your code broke.